# Prove that all square matrices with odd number of rows or columns have an eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A∈\mathbf R^{n×n}$, with $n$ odd. How can I prove that $\det(A-xI)$ equals zero for some $x∈\mathbf R$?

I have already known the way to solve this by means of polynomial's properties. Could you please provide a new angle to solve this?

Thx.

Comment: This is logically *equivalent* to the fact that every odd degree polynomial has a root in $\Bbb R$. (As in, if we replace $\Bbb R$ with any other field $F$ and let $S\subseteq \Bbb N$ be the set of all  $n$ such that every degree $n$ polynomial in $F[X]$ has a root in $F$, then all $A\in \Bbb F^{n\times n}$ have an eigenvalue iff $n\in S$)

Answer (score 4):

Any polynomial of odd degree on R will have at least one zero, as it goes to -infinity (hence becomes negative) when x goes to -infinity and to +infinity (hence becomes positive) when x goes to +infinity. By continuity, it must cancel at some point.

Comment: You are correct only if the leading coefficient is positive. If it's negative, the behavior is reversed, but we can again see that the polynomial has a zero